# Android App Links with Github Pages

Tags: android, github-pages, deep-linking, applinks

**What I want to do**

I have successfully set up deep linking for my app: When a link is opened, the user is asked to choose how to open it: Using my app or a browser.

I would like to use the new [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html) feature, where the app is automatically opened if it's installed.

To do this, the documentation states that I should create this file on my server:

https://hostname/.well-known/assetlinks.json.

**The problem**

The problem is that intent-filter data section is defined like:

```
<data android:scheme="https"
    android:host="myGithubUsername.github.io"
    android:pathPattern="/appname/groups/.*/join"/>
```

because my site is hosted on **Github Pages**.

So this can't work, because the file must be in *https://myGithubUsername.github.io*, but my website actually is *https://myGithubUsername.github.io/appname*

The alternative way would be to set `android:host="https://myGithubUsername.github.io/appname"` - but it doesn't work. The link isn't opened by the app at all.

Is there a way to use Android App Links with Github Pages?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Since you don't own `github.io` domain, you can't enable Android App Links feature.**

Using `android:host="https://myGithubUsername.github.io/appname"` doesn't since it is not a valid value for a `host` (aka domain name).

Comment: I believe it would work if I had a custom domain linked to my Github Page, but since I don't, your answer is correct.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. It is possible to test this feature on a github.io. refer to Nam Trung's answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Android Applink with Github Page. Just create a file named _config.yml in your root folder and the value inside is include: [".well-known"]. Here is the example

https://github.com/trungnn307/trungnn307.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml[image]

Comment: after wasting lots of time, finally able to verify. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, It is achievable. Just create repository named "**.well-known**" and add **assetlinks.json** file to it via upload.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't accomplish this by using github as your domain. I recommend using [Branch's Android SDK](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/). These links allow you to create a custom subdomain of *.app.link. For example, you could use appname.app.link. Branch handles all of the assetlinks hosting so you don't have to. In your link settings you could configure your `$fallback_url` of your links to be `https://myGithubUsername.github.io/appname`. This way when a user clicks one of these links, your app will open if it is installed, if not, the user will be directed to you github page. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Adding an empty file named `.nojekyll` can fix the problem. For more detail, see [this link](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Pages/Unable-to-access-resources-in-folder-with-name-starting-with/td-p/14995).

Comment: For my PWA published on github.io, this solution immediately solved the 404 error for /.well-known/assetlinks.json. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks